# Watir - How do I collect all links where the span contains aria_label "Multimedia"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, watir, ruby-watir

I have written a ruby code where the browser object finds all links and then I store them one by one in an array if they match a specific regex.

```
@browser.links.collect(&:href).each do |link|
  matches = regex.match(link)
  array_of_multimedia << matches[:multimedia_id] if matches
end
```

I am trying to create a filter where I only iterate over those links where the span inside the second child div contains the aria-label as *Multimedia*.

Attached is the screenshot of the HTML structure.[HTML structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBRes.png)

I tried a few approaches like finding all spans and then going bottom up to the parent's parent of the span but its not giving me the href.

```
@browser.spans(aria_label: "Multimedia").each do |span|
 span.parent.parent.a.hreflang #Didn't work
 span.parent.parent.a.link.href #Didn't work
 span.parent.parent.href.text #Didn't work
 element.tag_name #This shows "a" which is correct though
end
```

I also tried a top down approach by doing

```
@browser.links.collect(&:href).each do |link|
  link_element = @browser.link(href: link)
  link_element.children.following_sibling(aria_label: "Multimedia").present? #Didn't work
end
```

So far, no luck in getting the actual hrefs. Will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the span is inside the link tag, it's going to be easier to go bottom up

Do as much as you can with the Watir locators rather than multiple loops.
The parent method takes arguments:

```
@browser.spans(aria_label: 'Multimedia').map {|span| span.parent(tag_name: 'a').href }
```

As for what you tried:

```
# parent.parent is the link, so calling `#a` is looking for a link nested inside the link
span.parent.parent.a.hreflang
span.parent.parent.a.link.href 

# href should give you a String, you shouldn't need to call #text method on it
span.parent.parent.href.text 

# element isn't defined here, but try just element.href 
element.tag_name
```

Also note that `Element#href` method is essentially a wrapper for `Element#attribute_value('href')`.

Comment: Awesome. Really appreciate the detailed explanations and your help!
```@browser.spans(aria_label: 'Multimedia').map {|span| span.parent.parent(tag_name: 'a').href }```
worked for me.